# R CMD check looks for nonexisting file

Tags: r, rcpp, building

R CMD check looks for a nonexisting .R file when preparing package for lazy loading, Rcpp.package.skeleton produces seemingly corrupted RcppExports.cpp
file.

I am trying to build an R-package using Rcpp setting it up with a call to
Rcpp.package.skeleton. This produces a seemingly corrupted RcppExports.cpp
file (duplicate function definitions).

After manually correcting this file I run devtools::check() on this, compilation and linking succeeds and the dll is built. But then the following output from R CMD check

```
   ** R
   ** data
   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
   Reading DataUtils.R
   Reading Env.R
   Reading Paths.R
   Reading RcppExports.R
   Reading StatUtils.R
   Reading SynData.R
   Warnung in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding)
       cannot open file 'src/Env.R': No such file or directory
   Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
       cannot open file connection
   Error : unable to load R code in package 'ZA'
   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ZA'
   * removing 'C:/Users/MeyerM/Projects/R/ZA/ZA.Rcheck/ZA'
   In R CMD INSTALL
```

Why would it look for a file "src/Env.R"?

The package can be obtained from https://github.com/spyqqqdia/ZAp
(file ZAp.zip).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There should not be arch-dependent directories in a source tarball.  What exactly are you trying to, what are exactly are you doing, and how do you think we can help you with a non-reproducible question?

Comment: Moreover, if you have a bug in `devtools` you are barking up the wrong tree. We support the Rcpp commands listed in the Rcpp documentation.  What you used is not one of them (though it calls them).

Comment: @Dirk Edelbuettel

Comment: Almost.  We tend to write my family name with two Ds at the front. Eddelbuettel.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel
I am not accusing Rcpp of being buggy merely stating as background info that 
the package is being built with Rcpp (via call to Rcpp.package.sekeleton).
The problem seems to be with R CMD check (which produces the exact same error).
I can only hope that someone has had a similar problem and may thus be able to help.

Comment: If you can point to a repo, or mock up a repo exibitiing the same behaviour, we can try to take a look.  With what you gave us so far we cannot help.

Comment: Use of the `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` function is part of the unit tests and stressed at each release, at each git commit, at CRAN nightly, ... so it is unlikely to be buggy per se.  Your setep could be different -- I don;t set `LANG=de` etc pp.  But again we have user across the globe so _we really need something reproducible_.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel OK. Give me alittle time (say 3 days), I'll clean up the code and put it on Github.

Comment: Deal.  If it is a bug you can of course also come to the GH repo with an issue.  And I would delete this Q here ...

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel OK I'll delete it and will be back once this is on Github. Btw. I am a great fan and grateful user of Rcpp and your work.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel I have uploaded the package to https://github.com/spyqqqdia/ZAp. If you take a look at it this would be greatly appreciated. Detailed description is in docs/README.txt.

Comment: Please make it a normal source repository.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Made it a normal repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors in that code:

1. Duplicate `// [[Rcpp::export]]` before function declaration and definition. This leads to the redefinition errors from compiling `RcppExports.cpp`.
2. Using `string` instead of `std::string` or `using std::string` in some files.
3. Code that **must not** be part of a package, e.g. `compileCpp.R`:

   ```
   source("src/Env.R")
   library(Rcpp)
   ```

As a first approximation, files in `R` should only contain function definitions.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Where should the // [[Rcpp::export]] attributes be, in the header or in the source?

Comment: @gcc I would use the definition, but it seems to be a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

Your repo / code is bad:

```
edd@rob:/tmp/so$ git clone git@github.com:spyqqqdia/ZAp.git
Cloning into 'ZAp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 52, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (52/52), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
remote: Total 52 (delta 3), reused 52 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (52/52), 31.78 KiB | 986.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
edd@rob:/tmp/so$ ls
ZAp
edd@rob:/tmp/so$ build.r ZAp                 # R CMD build wrapper
* checking for file ‘ZAp/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘ZAp’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* cleaning src
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘ZAp_1.0.tar.gz’

edd@rob:/tmp/so$ rcc.r ZAp_1.0.tar.gz        # R CMD check wrapper
── R CMD check ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─  using log directory ‘/tmp/file3d684dd243a4/ZAp.Rcheck’
─  using R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
─  using platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
─  using session charset: UTF-8
✔  checking for file ‘ZAp/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  checking extension type ... Package
─  this is package ‘ZAp’ version ‘1.0’
✔  checking package namespace information
✔  checking package dependencies (519ms)
W  checking if this is a source package
   Subdirectory ‘src’ contains:
     PathGenerator.hpp matrix.hpp paths.hpp swap.hpp swapprogram.hpp
     utils.hpp
   These are unlikely file names for src files.
✔  checking if there is a namespace
✔  checking for executable files ...
✔  checking for hidden files and directories
✔  checking for portable file names
✔  checking for sufficient/correct file permissions
E  checking whether package ‘ZAp’ can be installed (5.1s)

   See
     ‘/tmp/file3d684dd243a4/ZAp.Rcheck/00check.log’
   for details.

   Installation failed.
   See ‘/tmp/file3d684dd243a4/ZAp.Rcheck/00install.out’ for details.
edd@rob:/tmp/so$
```

The wrappers are from littler and don't matter. Your code is bad -- it does not build. Pay attention to warnings and notes. All of them.

The compiler tells me about a bazillion redefinitions.  You appear to have issues here.  Try something simpler for a start, make it work, build up from there.

Comment: There are no redefinitions in my source. They are in RcppExports.cpp and have to manually eliminated, see the comments in docs/package_building.txt.The automatic generation of RcppExports.cpp by Rcpp.package.skeleton seems to do this.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel There are no redefinitions in my source. I do not understand why Rcpp.package.skeleton writes duplicate definitions into RcppExports.cpp -- which is part of the question. Regarding the unlikely source file name warning: where are we supposed to put the headers?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not have time for people who think they must reinvent the build process. This works for over 1550 packages on CRAN which use Rcpp, probably a few thousand more at GitHub and GitLab and $deity knows how many in the wild.  I encourage you to get more familiar with the how and why.  And as I said:  start from something simpler. Make it work.  Build up.  Good luck.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel Let me know where you think it was reinvented, because surely there must be the problem.